# GNU Radio: Some custom code in he middle of two blocks in GRC flowgraphs

Tags: python, pyqt, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I need to apply a math formula (e.g. take a square root) to every sample (of 64 element vector) in the data stream coming out from a GRC signal source block (e.g.Complex to Mag Phase block in the attached GRC flowgraph) using Python code, just before that stream gets passed on to some other block down the stream (e.g. QT GUI Time Sink in the attached GRC flowgraph)

I will be applying phase unwrapping to the 64 sample phase vector before it is displayed to time sink.

[image: Example GRC flow graph]

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Were you expecting someone to write all the code for you?

Comment: I have this flowgraph with me, and its auto-generated python code. I need to know how to capture the FFT phase and then lets say apply some scaling (or phase unwrapping in my case) and pass it to the QT GUI Sink for display.

Comment: That is way, way too broad for an SO question. Start writing some code yourself first, and then come back when you have a much more specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, you'll need to write a block, as you already noticed!

Writing blocks isn't that hard; the intro on

http://tutorials.gnuradio.org

should at least give you the ability to implement what you want.